# Why does Windows 10 seem to ignore the DNS query replied from my router?

Tags: windows-10, router, dns, hosts-file, dnsmasq

I have an OpenWRT router. I have added few entries to the `/etc/hosts` file on the router, to block the users from accessing some of the websites. Recently, I have upgraded a computer to Windows 10, and I found that I can access the blocked websites on that computer after the upgrade.

I tried to `nslookup` the domain name, it is found that the actual IP address is returned on the Win10 computer, while the IP address defined in `/etc/hosts` is returned on other device [(Capture1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Us4N.png).

So I used Wireshark to capture the DNS query, to see what is actually happening when Windows 10 is doing DNS query. It is found that the router DID replied the DNS query with the IP address defined in the hosts file [(Capture 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnRUa.png), but the nslookup result is still the actual IP address.

To confirm that the problem is not from the router itself, I have added a non-existing domain entry to the hosts file and do `nslookup` again. This time the defined IP address is returned.

I have confirmed that I have disabled other network interfaces (which are the virtual machine bridge interfaces), the primary network interface is also set to use the DNS server from DHCP only, and no secondary DNS server is defined. Also, before doing nslookup, I have `ipconfig /flushdns` to prevent any domain record from caching on the system.

It seems that Windows 10 is just ignoring the DNS query replied from my router, and is querying another DNS servers for the actual IP address of a domain name. Is it possible to disable such behavior?  Or if there is another problem that cause such behavior?

---Edited---

Here's the `ipconfig /all` output

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Sunny-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 60-A4-4C-2E-4D-8C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 28 January 2017 02:03:40
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 28 January 2017 14:03:40
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{606D8EC0-C791-4C68-BC6D-B051FFF5FD50}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:4cc:142e:2598:228a(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4cc:142e:2598:228a%22(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 167772160
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-12-38-C3-60-A4-4C-2E-4D-8C
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: Can you provide us the output to `ipconfig /all` by chance on the device that isn't working?

Comment: @Ramhound The question is edited to also include the ipconfig /all output, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply rebooting the router?

Comment: Changing DNS to block web sites really isn't very effective, anyway. There are real methods to accomplish that.

Comment: Try to disable `IP helper` service, it will disable tunneling over teredo that can still be used for name resolution

Answer (score 3):

OK, thanks to the "**Secure DNS**" feature of Avast! Antivirus, I have wasted 2 days to troubleshoot the problem.

I found that when my computer send a DNS query to my router, a query to a strange IP address will also be sent. I tried to check the query content, but the packet is encrypted. So I whois-ed the IP address, and found that the IP address belongs to Avast.

After disabled the "Secure DNS" feature (Avast Setting -> Components), the DNS resolve process back to normal now.

Comment: It's called "RealSite" in the latest versions of Avast. Thanks for posting the solution. Really helped me.